# UIImage initWithData how to wait until complete

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, core-graphics, quartz-2d

When I load an BMP image this way:

```
NSData * pImageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:pBuffer length:dwSize freeWhenDone:NO];
UIImage * pLoaded = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:pImageData];
[pImageData release];
```

and try to display that image with Quartz2D:

```
CGImageRef cgImage = [pLoaded CGImage];
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, x, y*2 + h);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(x, y, w, h), cgImage);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

The image displays as black rectangle or sometimes it is displayed but not fully. When I put sleep for 1 second after initWithData, image is displayed correctly.

Is there an UIKit/Quartz2D API method to wait for image initialization complete?

Comment: maybe this is because you change the data in pBuffer. Does it work when you use `dataWithBytes:length:`?

Comment: try replacing CGContextDrawImage(...) with `[pLoaded drawInRect:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)]`

Comment: I don't know why but it works when I use `initWithBytes` instead of `initWithBytesNoCopy` to initialize `pImageData`. Thx phix23 for your help. BTW `pBuffer` is not touched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works when I use:

```
NSData * pImageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:pBuffer length:dwSize];
```

instead of:

```
NSData * pImageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:pBuffer length:dwSize freeWhenDone:NO];
```

Thanks goes to phix23.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@synchronization` or `dispatch` queue to wait until your image download get finished.